# Data processing pipeline design for processing data

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, python, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I have a use case for which I need to build a data processing pipeline

- Customer contact leads data coming from different data sources like csv, data base, api has to be first **mapped** to a universal schema fields. There could be ~100k rows coming each day that need to be processed.
- Then some of the fields have to be cleansed, validated and enriched. For example- the email field has to be validated by calling an **external API** to check if it's valid and does not bounce, address field has to be standardized to a particular format. There are other operations like estimating city, state from zip, phone number validation. Atleast 20 operations already planned, more to come in future
- The above rules are **not fixed** and can change based on what user wants to do with his data (saved from user interface). For example, for a particular data, a user may only choose to standardize his phone number, but not check if its valid: thus operations performed on the data is dynamic.

Here is what I am doing currently:

1. Load the data as a **pandas data** frame(have considered spark. But data set is not that large[max 200 mb-]to use spark). Have a list of user-defined operations that need to be performed on each field like

   actions = {"phone_number": ['cleanse', 'standardise'], "zip": ["enrich", "validate"]}

As I mentioned above, the **actions are dynamic** and vary from the data source to data source based on what user choose to do on each field. There is lot many custom business like this that can be applied specifically to a specific field.

2. I have a custom function for each operation that user can define for fields.
   I call them based on the "actions" dictionary and pass the data frame to the function - the function applies the logic written to the data frame and returns the modified data frame.

> ```
> def cleanse_phone_no(df, configs):
>     # Logic
>     return modified_df
> ```

I am not sure if this is the right approach to do it. Things are going to get complicated when I have to call external API's to do enrichment of certain fields in future. So I am considering a **producer-consumer model**

a. Have a producer module that creates that splits **each row in file**(1 contact record) as single message in a queue like AMQ or Kafka

b. Have the logic to process the data in consumers - they will take one message at a time and process them

c. The advantage I see with this approach is -it simplifies the data processing part- data is processed one record at a time. There is more control and granularity Disadvantage is it will create overhead in terms of computation as a record in processed one by one - which I can overcome to an extent using multiple consumers

Here are my questions:

- What is your opinion about the approach? Do you have any suggestions for a better approach?
- Is there any more elegant pattern I can use to apply the custom rules to the data set that what I am using currently
- Is using a producer-consumer model to process the data one row at a time than entire data set advisable (considering all the complexity in logic that would come in future)? If so should I use AMQ or Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

> Is using a producer-consumer model to process the data one row at a
> time than entire data set advisable (considering all the complexity in
> logic that would come in future)?

Taking bulk data at once and processing it certainly has its own benefit, in terms of network calls involved and the benefit significantly grows up when your  external APIs support bulk operations.

You can simply get all the records which needs call to some external service X and then send all these records to that external service and get the result in one go.

---

Producer-Consumer is typically used for continuous stream of data. While it is true that you can have multiple consumers in order to have better scaling. While using Kafka, it is important how you partition the data.

Since the operations you will be performing on each row differs and may change over time gradually, you need to figure out how do you partition them, in a way that you do not get a performance hit.

If records belonging to the same partition should have to call multiple external services and other records are just simple, then one consumer may be doing less work (or even sit idle) and the other may be overloaded.

So, what I suggest here is if you can *determine, for sure* the partitioning logic, then you may go ahead with this approach. Also, you mentioned:

> The above rules are not fixed and can change based on what user wants
> to do with his data

You need to write your producer in such a way that it calculates some *weight/cost* for each customer record based on how much processing is involved for that record. Based on this cost, you can write your partitioning logic.

---

> Is there any more elegant pattern I can use to apply the custom rules
> to the data set that what I am using currently

You can divide the processing into stages, execute them one after the other and each stage will store its output to an intermediate topic. For example,

> cleansed -> standardized -> enriched -> validated

The advantages you get here:

1. Inspect failures in data processing easily as to which stage a record has failed.
2. Reducing the overhead of *full* processing one record at a time.
3. Better code in each stage - Because you make external service calls pertaining to that stage only.
4. Access to *intermediate* data as may be needed by any applications in future.
   Eg, you may discard fake email during validation but in some cases you might want to know the customers who have used fake emails.

While creating this pipeline, you need to be generic in terms of the pipeline stages, the record fields will determine the processing logic at each stage. For example, validating an email is different from validating a mobile number.

> If so should I use AMQ or Kafka?

Refer to [this answer for AMQ vs Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529912/2534090).